# How can I view FS:[0] with windbg?

Tags: x86, windbg

It seems that Windows 8 broke Ollydbg as several `ntdll` functions keep throwing exception `0xC0000008` and crashing my debugger.

I am now using Windbg.  But, I am unable to view `FS` (specifically `FS:[0]`).  How can I get a dump of `FS` via Windbg? I've tried googling to no avail.  I am specifically interested in SEH, but all I can find is dumping TEB or PEB.

Comment: 0xc0000008 is triggered by a call to CloseHandle() with an invalid handle value, while a debugger is present.  It is not a fatal exception, and is a common anti-debugging trick.  Why do you think that Windows 8 is responsible?

Comment: Debugging the same app under Windows 7 with the same debugger does not cause any problems.  I figured it was something with the OS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SEH chain can be viewed in WinDbg by issuing `!exchain` command.

```
0:000> !exchain    # display the SEH chain
0012ffb0: wireshark!_except_handler4+0 (00522555)
0012ffe0: kernel32!_except_handler3+0 (7c839ac0)
  CRT scope  0, filter: kernel32!BaseProcessStart+29 (7c843882)
                func:   kernel32!BaseProcessStart+3a (7c843898)
Invalid exception stack at ffffffff
```

`FS:[0]` is the pointer to the start of **SEH chain**. You can walk through the output produced by `!exchain` to find `FS:[0]`

Answer (score 16):

If you're looking to find the base address of a segment based on its selector, you can use `dg`*`<selector>`*; in this context you would use `dg fs`:

```
0:000> dg fs
                                  P Si Gr Pr Lo
Sel    Base     Limit     Type    l ze an es ng Flags
---- -------- -------- ---------- - -- -- -- -- --------
003B 7ffdf000 00000fff Data RW Ac 3 Bg By P  Nl 000004f3
```

You can see above that the `Base` of `fs` is `7ffdf000`, so `FS:[0] == [7ffdf000]`.

```
0:000> db 7ffdf000
7ffdf000  1c f7 1d 00 00 00 1e 00-00 f0 1c 00 00 00 00 00  ................
7ffdf010  00 1e 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 f0 fd 7f 00 00 00 00  ................
7ffdf020  0c 13 00 00 bc 0f 00 00-00 00 00 00 2c f0 fd 7f  ............,...
7ffdf030  00 a0 fd 7f 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
7ffdf040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
7ffdf050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
7ffdf060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
7ffdf070  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intersted in viewing SEH, consider using [pydbg SEH unwinding](http://pedramamini.com/PaiMei/docs/PyDbg/public/pydbg.pydbg.pydbg-class.html#seh_unwind) for that kind of purposes.