# Windbg: How to directly view GS:[0x60]

Tags: windbg, x86-64, windows-10

Win10x64: In Windbg, how may I view a pointer to the `PEB` by directly using `GS:[0x60]` (and not by Windbg extensions)?

To test, I assembled a program via masm64 that throws an interrupt, clears `r8` then moves a pointer to the `PEB` to `r8`:

```
(3a4.2034): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (!!! second chance !!!)
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\Users\res\Desktop\cfg\test.exe
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for C:\Users\res\Desktop\cfg\test.exe
test+0x10c1:
00007ff6cedf10c1 4d33c0          xor     r8,r8
0:000> r
rax=00007ff6cedf1000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=00007ff6cedf1068
rdx=00007ff6cedf1075 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=00007ff6cedf10c1 rsp=0000006642d8f730 rbp=0000000000000000
r8=0000000000000000  r9=00007ff6cedf1000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000000 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b               efl=00000244`
```

Afterwards, [I checked the base address for GS via selector](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5868/how-can-i-view-fs0-with-windbg), but it's not populated:

```
0:000> dg gs
                                                P Si Gr Pr Lo
Sel        Base              Limit          Type    l ze an es ng Flags`
---- ----------------- ----------------- ---------- - -- -- -- -- --------
002B 00000000 00000000 00000000 ffffffff Data RW Ac 3 Bg Pg P  Nl 00000cf3`
```

Naturally its null when I try to dump `GS:[0x60]`.

However, when I step into the instruction that moves the `PEB` pointer into `r8`, `r8` has a distinct value!:

```
test+0x10c4:
00007ff6 cedf10c4 654c8b042560000000 mov   r8,qword ptr gs:[60h]    gs:00000000 00000060=????????????????
0:000> t
test+0x10cd:
00007ff6 cedf10cd 4d8b4018        mov     r8,qword ptr [r8+18h]   ds:00000066 42e0a018={ntdll!PebLdr (00007ff8 c642f3a0)}
0:000> r
rax=00007ff6cedf1000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=00007ff6cedf1068
rdx=00007ff6cedf1075 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=00007ff6cedf10cd rsp=0000006642d8f730 rbp=0000000000000000
r8=0000006642e0a000  r9=00007ff6cedf1000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000000 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b               efl=00000246
test+0x10cd:
00007ff6 cedf10cd 4d8b4018        mov     r8,qword ptr [r8+18h] ds:00000066 42e0a018={ntdll!PebLdr (00007ff8 c642f3a0)}`
```

Answer (score 1):

`dg gs` seems to be not supported on x64, as stated by the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/dg--display-selector-), so you can not rely on it.

If you want to see where `gs` points to, you can use `!teb` or `rdmsr c0000102`.